# invalid pixel in Firefox because of content charset setting in Netty server

Tags: http, firefox, character-encoding, netty

I am developing an http server with Netty. On some occasions, the server must answer a 1x1 transparent pixel. So I hard-coded a GIF transparent pixel in base64, and returned it with the following code :

```
String pixel_string= new String (Base64.decodeBase64("R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="));
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(pixel_string, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

EDIT : I also set the content-type :
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "image/gif");
In Chrome, everything is fine. However, Firefox tells me that it cannot display the pixel (which is pretty bad for my app), as the pixel data in invalid.
After many investigations, I finally figured out a fix, by changing the charset to Iso-8859-1.

```
response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(
            responseBuilder.pixel_string, CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1));
```

I don't understand why it works, which makes me think that I may run into troubles in some cases. I tried to change the Firefox preferences (to have UTF8 as default), but it doesn't change much.

**Why does Firefox accept the ISO-8859 encoding, and not UTF-8 ?** Can I change that ? Would someone have a clue on the origin of the issue and how to be sure that it will work whatever the user's setting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Firefox that's accepting the encoding or not.  It's your server.

When you do your base64 decode you produce a string that contains some characters... but what you really produced was *bytes* that you're then thinking of as characters somehow.  Since a Java String is a container that holds a UTF-16 string, in practice what you're doing is taking each byte, treating it as a a 16-bit integer and constructing the UTF-16 "string" made up of those code units.

But when you want to put all this on the network, you have to convert you string to bytes, and the argument to `copiedBuffer` says how to do that.  If converting to UTF-8, any character that came from a byte that had the high bit set will end up getting encoded as a two-byte UTF-8 sequence.  On the other hand, if converting to ISO-8859-1, the conversion just drops the high byte of each UTF-16 code unit (which in your case is always zero anyway).

So the conversion to ISO-8859-1 produces the actual byte array you got out of base64-decoding, while the conversion to UTF-8 produces.... something else which may or may not actually make any sense depending on the exact byte values.

Comment: Thanks Boris, my understanding of your answer is that I should avoid storing the pixel code in a String, and favor a byte array. I'll try that.

Comment: @Pixou Yeah, I think using a byte array here would be a much better fit for what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The `copiedBuffer` constructor you call is not appropriate for the type of data (binary) you are using. According to the JavaDoc of the Netty API, the one you are calling is:

> Creates a new big-endian buffer whose content is the specified string
>   encoded in the specified charset.

Which means that your binary data is being "converted" to UTF-8 (which is meaningless). If you try to save the generated file and look at it with a hex editor, you'll probably see that it is corrupted.

Try with something like this (untested code):

```
static byte[] pixel_data = Base64.decodeBase64("R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");
HttpResponse response = ...
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/gif");
response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(pixel_data));
```

Comment: I edited my question : I do set the content-type. Image files are binary, but I need to specify the charset as I use a String to store the image in my code. Maybe I should use a byte [] instead of String

Comment: I edited my answer too, according to your edit... hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ale, I'll try that, as also advised by Boris

Comment: You could use `wrappedBuffer` rather than `copiedBuffer`.